# How old is Milo? Does he have a family?

Tags: norton-juster, the-phantom-tollbooth

*The Phantom Tollbooth* is all about the boy Milo's voyage of discovery through the allegorical lands of Wisdom (and Ignorance). At the beginning of the story, he starts off in the real world being bored and dissatisfied, seemingly with nothing to do or enjoy in his life. When he returns after everything he's seen and done, he finds himself and the world around him full of life and interest, and even says he's too busy to go back and re-start his adventure.

**Do we know anything more about his life in the real world?** Does he have parents? How old is he? Any information at all?

Answer (score 7):

I seem to recall "Milo," the boy who eventually restores the sisters, Rhyme & Reason, to the Kingdom of Knowledge, as being said to be 10 years of age.

In Chapter 9, a boy in the sky discusses the following perspective with Milo:

> "What a silly system." The boy laughed. "Then your head keeps changing its height and you always see things in a different way? Why, when you're fifteen things won't look at all the way they did when you were ten, and at twenty everything will change again."
>
> "I suppose so," replied Milo, for he had never really thought about the matter."

Though it's not definitive, this passage suggests that Milo is now seeing the world from the height of a 10-year-old.

Answer (score 5):

There is no explicit information in the story, which I assume was intentional to allow readers to more closely identify with Milo. What we know is that he lives in an apartment building with an elevator and goes to school. He's young enough to have a toy car he can drive. He's apparently a latchkey kid which is unusual for the era at which the book was published. I first encountered *The Phantom Tollbooth* in excerpts which illustrated Milo as an African-American boy so even with the Jules Feiffer illustrations, I still tend to think of him as African-American.

My own personal take is that he's a fourth grader (roughly 9–10 years old), but that's largely based on the age I was when I first read *The Phantom Tollbooth*.

Comment: Any chance you can edit this to include the age a typical fourth grader is? That isn't automatic knowledge for people outside the US.

Comment: @Spagirl I've updated it.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume Milo is American? (Certainly that's not something that can be deduced from illustrations.)